# how to implement the query based on the places range from x minutes to xx minutes time for drive?

Tags: php, here-maps-rest

There are some places I can choose from. I want to choose one to be my source place, and select driving time cost is less than 30 minutes. So there are maybe some places I can drive there cost less than 30 minutes will be showed.

So, what is the best way I should to save all these places data and query them on specific conditions?

Before I asking this question, I've tried to save all these places latitude and longitude. Whenever a new place has been saved to the database, I will request HERE map routing API to calculate distances and drive time between the new one with all old places info in a database, then save them in the distance table.

When a user wants to query places like the above example. I will join places table and distance table to query like:

```
SELECT place.id, place.name from place join distance on place_id = place.id where distance cost_time < 30;
```

There are some problem make me upset. If the number of old places is too big(actually it will), the time hanging after saving a place to the database will be much more.

So, I know I used a bad method to implement my goal. But I don't know how can I do, can someone help me with this problem?

last but not least, forget my poor English, if something is unclear, I'll try my best to describe it. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to build a connected graph and compute the distances to other points on the fly.

When a new point is added, compute its  distance with the X nearest neighbours only and store them in a database.

Then, you can use a algorithm like [Dijkstra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dijkstra%27s_algorithm) to find all the points at less than 30 units from your source.

You will lose some precision, as the cost to drive from A to C, then C to B will be usually greater then the direct path from A to B. And the time you saved on adding a new point, you will "lost" it to do the computation of the Dijkstra algorithm.

Comment: What you mean is that I still need to calculate the distance between all the locations through the API, but when I store it in the database, I need to save it in the form of a graph data structure. When I take it out according to the conditions, should I calculate it by Dijkstra algorithm?